# On insertion of checkbox data in codeigniter it insert 'on' in the database value

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php


class Register extends CI_controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library(array('session','email'));
    
       
    }

      function index(){
        
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
            
        /* Validation rule */
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'required|valid_email|callback_check_customer');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[15]');
             
               
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { 
               $this->load->view('register'); 
                 } 
            else { 
                $this->load->model('Register_model');
                $data = array(
                    'u_name' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                    'mob' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
                    'hobbies' => $this->input->post('hobby'),
                    'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                    'address' => $this->input->post('add'),
                    'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
                    
                );
               $this->Register_model->signupdata($data);
               $success = "Your account has been successfully created!";
                       $this->load->view('register', compact('success')); 
                  } 

     }
    public function check_customer($email)
     {
            $query = $this->db->where('email', $email)->get("log_details");
                    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
                       {
                        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_customer','The '.$email.' belongs to an existing account');
                           return FALSE;
                       }
                     else 
                         return TRUE;
                 }    
    
}
      
?>
```

Comment: Did you have a question? When a checkbox is selected it has a value of "on".

Comment: No, it has some other value but when I insert the value of checkbox in database it is taking 'on' as a value.

Comment: A checkbox may have a name but it's value when sent back to PHP will be on if it is checked. If it is not checked it will not be sent back to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Check input checkbox you have to assign value to checkbox in value attribute:

`<input type="checkbox" name="chekbox" value="123" />`